# Can Flare animations for Flutter be applied to interactive UI elements?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Can animations be applied to interactive elements like buttons? Or can we make interactive UI elements with specific components in a flare animation?

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Comment: Flare Create vector design and animation that can be Directly Used in App as an Asset. Its Doesn't Animate the Flutter already pre-defined Widgets or Anything. You have to create your own Button vector in flare with Custom Animation & use in App.